# DBContext (entity framework) and pre-loaded entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity

I use code first in a web application where I have a form to upload text files and import the data into my database.
Each file may have up to 20.000+ records for import.
To speed things up I preload some entities so not to ask the DbContext every time. Then when I create an object for insert, I do for example:

```
myNewObject.Category = preloadedCategories.First(p => p.Code == code);
```

I have read some articles on the web because EF is extremey slow on batch inserts, so what I do is:

1. first use `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false`;
2. then every 1000 records I dispose the object and make a new one.

BUT! since the preloaded entities where loaded from a db context that was disposed, after making a new DbContext, I have a problem with `preloadedCategories.First(p => p.Code == code)`. When I make a `SaveChanges()`, EF tries to also save the `preloadedCategories.First(p => p.Code == code)` object and fails.

So how can I achive this? I don't want to aks the DbContext every time to load some (non changing) objects. Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: Do you have a category ID property on your object? You can set that instead. For example: `myNewObject.CategoryID = preloadedCategories.First(p => p.Code == code).ID;`

Comment: sorry ment to write that. I also used that, but I have the same problem

Comment: Can you load the entities with .NoTracking() for performance? if you are just going to read them. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556203.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a large number of records in EF, a few things will help

1. As @janhartmann states, use `.AsNoTracking()`
2. As you stated, use `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false`, which will require the next point
3. Use `context.Categories.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified` to attach a disconnected entity to a context and mark is as modified

Also make check that `preloadedCategories` is no longer an `IQuerable` and that the data really is local and not trying to lazy load from the database.

If there are no changes to your `Category` object and you just want to link your `myNewObject` to an existing category, you have two options

1. Set the foreign key on `myNewObject` instead of the navigation property
2. Use `context.Products.Entry(myNewObject).State = EntitySate.Added` instead of `context.Products.Add(myNewObject)` to avoid it adding the entire graph of navigation properties

Good luck